# Binary format of the specified custom attribute was invalid

Tags: asp.net

I have an application in framework version 4.0. It was earlier in 3.5 version and has been converted to 4.0. Every time the application is deployed, iisreset is done and the application url is for the first time i get a error like -

"**Binary format of the specified custom attribute was invalid.**".

I read somewhere that whenever something is updated, the app pool has to be recycled and this was not there with previous versions of the framework but needs to be done with 4.0. But every time i do an iisreset the app pool is recycled. So it is not working in my case.

Anybody else have any other ways to fix the problem. Would be really helpful.